# How can I have a chromeless YouTube player and start/stop playback whenever I want?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I want to have a Chromeless player that I can control via JS in terms of stop and start.

My player code, so far is:

`<iframe class="video-frame" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xU1S011111?controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

I'm not sure how to interact with the JS API however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite a few examples can be found here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

You need to add `&enablejsapi=1` to the URL, set an `id`, then add the JavaScript shown in that sample (using `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`):

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" class="video-frame" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xU1S011111?controls=0&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I could copy and paste a bunch of example code, but you'll understand better if you read the docs.  They're readable and easy to use.

Here's a fiddle demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/BAqTe/

Comment: The important thing is to make sure your iframe element has an id= property set, since you need to pass that id in to the YT.Player constructor. The jsfiddle has that set, but your answer doesn't.